# explanation on the mimo technique

Tags: digital-communications

In MIMO systems we have:
$y=Hx+n$ with $H$ is a matrix $N_r \times N_t$.

But the previous equation is only true for non-frequency selective channels.

What is the formula for frequency-selective channels?

---

Normally, $y=h \star x +n$. But if H is a matrix, we can not the convolution. How to solve this problem

Comment: $H$ becomes three dimensional matrix of which the third dimension is frequency.

Answer (score 2):

The channel gain can be written in the form of a linear time-varying filter.
Let $h(t,\tau)$ denotes the channel impulse response at time $\tau$. Thus, the received signal can be written for SISO case as
$$ y(t,\tau) = h(t,\tau)\star x(t) + n(t)$$
where $n(t)$ is the AWGN. In MIMO case, the signal observed at the $j$-th receive antenna can be written as
$$y_j(t,\tau) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_T} h_{i,j}(t,\tau)x_i(t) +n_j(t)$$

Here, if the channel is slow-varying, we can omit the time instance dependency $\tau$:

$$y_j(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_T}h_{i,j}(t)x_i(t) +n_j(t)$$

Based on the expression above you can now define:
$$\mathbf{y}(t) = \mathbf{H(t)} \mathbf{x}(t) + \mathbf{n}(t)$$

In addition, for a time interval of interest, (i.e. a signaling period) if the channel matrix is static, we can simply write the above expression in a very simple form as

$$ \mathbf{y} =  \mathbf{H}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{n}$$

which is obtained by omitting the time dependency $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The input-otput relation for frequency selective channel:

$y_i=\sqrt{\frac{P}{M_T}}H_is_i+n_i$

More information can be found [here](http://web.stanford.edu/group/introstwc/Course%20Notes/lect6.pdf).

Comment: I am afraid the link doesn't work. Would you update your answer if possible?